# AngularJS: Retrieving Videogular templates stored in $templateCache results 404 Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http-status-code-404, videogular

I currently develop an **AngularJS** *1.5.9* **Single Page Application** on my localhost with **NodeJS** running backend, where I use

**Videogular** framework. http://www.videogular.com/

Everything is fine except inserting videogular object on my page. I strictly follow the given example: http://www.videogular.com/examples/simplest-videogular-player/

```
<videogular vg-theme="controller.config.theme.url">
    <vg-media vg-src="controller.config.sources"
              vg-tracks="controller.config.tracks"
              vg-native-controls="true">
    </vg-media>
</videogular>
```

But it results in AngularJS error:

[image: Error]

*(`sessionId` in the request is the auth token not linked to current problem)*

I have found the following in `videogular.js` :

```
$templateCache.put("vg-templates/vg-media-video", "<video></video>");
$templateCache.put("vg-templates/vg-media-audio", "<audio></audio>");
```

I have tried to store files locally, and the error disappeared

[image: Local]

Actually there are a lot of plugins for Videogular and they all are using `$templateCache` to store some files in the cache, so it would be very confusing to manually store them locally in my app folder.

How can such files be stored in the cache using `$templateCache` so they can be  extracted properly?

I apreciate your help.

**UPDATE**

I have tried insert `$templateCache.get` to directive, where the part is loading with error 404, and it works. But still doesn't work as it supposed to be.

[image: issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is an issue with sessionId that you pass in URL parametrs, do you actually need it?

I guess your interceptor or whatever auth managing module is wrong configured, so you don't check request target URL and id parameters are going to be added for local calls as well as for backend calls.

Comment: You are definetely right!
I have my interceptor wrong configured. Thank you!